# QCustomplot Graphs are not showing if not debugging

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I am using qcustomplot to plot some graphs.
I initialized the QCustomPlot object and added 10 graphs.

Mainly, the application contains a menue that when clicked, it performs some calculations then show the result graphs.

If I am debugging the application, i get the graphs shown.
If I am not debugging, only the legend is shown!!!

Does anyone has an explanation to this behaviour?

Comment: There is no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and you don't provide enough context. So this is just a shot into the blue: Regarding C++ in VisualStudio, whenever I had well behavior in debug mode and sporadic errors in release mode there was mostly a simple problem: Somewhere I forgot to initialize plain-old data (e.g. a `bool` or `int` or even anything`*`). In debug mode, VS fills everything with patterns like `0xcdcdcdcd` as debug aid. It doesn't do so in release mode. Thus, in debug mode everything is initialized somehow but not (anymore) in release mode...

Comment: Btw. you should tag the programming language also you use.

Comment: I'm using C++, QT.

Comment: OK. Please, use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43932047/edit) link (just below of the tags) to add the tag.